# Migrating away from bodyParser() in Express app with busboy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, express, busboy

Being a newbie in Nodejs, I jumped right into writing a simple app without really reading up on good security practices. I just found out that using `bodyParser()` for all routes is actually [a bad thing because it allows for DOS attack using multipart files](http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html).

A recommended fix is to only load specific modules depending on the route. ie, for multipart fileupload, use `multipart`. For regular POST without file uploads (ie, text form submission), use `express.json(), express.urlencoded()`.

Or another option is to use [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) with [connect-busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy). But the thing I'm confused on is how I can specify which route should handle multipart data and which should not? Otherwise, wouldn't I have the same problem as with `bodyParser`?

Furthermore, `busboy` docs says it does not handle `GET`:

```
If you find that req.busboy is not defined in your code when you expect it to be, check that the following conditions are met. If they are not, req.busboy won't be defined:
  1. The request method is not GET or HEAD
```

So, I'm even more confused how I would parse `params` in a `GET`. I think `bodyParser` does this for me so I could access data with `req.params`.

For example, how would I migrate away from `bodyParser()` to `busboy/connect-busboy` with this simple app:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
app.use(busboy());

// How to use busboy to prevent multipart files here?
app.post("/form_data_no_fileupload", function(req, res) {
    var somedata = req.body.somedata;
});

// Use busboy to handle both regular form data + fileuploads 
app.post("/form_data_AND_fileupload", function(req, res) {

});

// What would handle GET without bodyparser?
app.get("/get_something", function(req, res) {
    var params = req.params;
});

http.listen(3000, function() {});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [How] I can specify which route should handle multipart data and which should not?

All of Express' [routing methods](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.METHOD) allow for providing middleware specific to the route. This includes [`Router` methods](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.METHOD).

> `app.METHOD(path, callback [, callback ...])`

Depending on the body expected for an individual route, you can use different modules to handle each of them (rather than applying them to the entire application with `app.use()`).

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');

app.post("/form_data_no_fileupload",
    bodyParser.urlencoded(),
    function(req, res, next) {
        // check that the request's body was as expected
        if (!req.body) return next('route'); // or next(new Error('...'));

        // ...
    });

app.post("/form_data_AND_fileupload",
    busboy({
        limits: {
            fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024
        }
    }),
    function(req, res, next) {
        // check that the request's body was as expected
        if (!req.busboy) return next('route'); // or next(new Error('...'));

        // ...
    });

// ...
```

> Furthermore, busboy docs says it does not handle GET.
>
> So, I'm even more confused how I would parse `params` in a `GET`.

Busboy and BodyParser are designed for reading in and parsing the request's body, which [`GET` and `HEAD` requests aren't expected to have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body).

For such requests, parameters can only be passed within the [query-string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) within the URL, which Express parses itself. They're available via [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.query).

```
app.get('/get_something', function () {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    // "/get_something?id=1

    console.log(req.query);
    // { id: "1" }
});
```

[`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params) represents any placeholders matched in the path by the route. These are available for any route, regardless of the method.

```
app.get('/thing/:id', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    // "/thing/2"

    console.log(req.params);
    // { id: "2" }
});
```

Comment: If I'm manually loading them into `app.post`, I no longer need to declare `app.use(bodyparser.json());` or `app.use(busboy())'`?

Comment: @rublex Sorry. Yes, you can remove those if they're instead given to the routes that actually require them.